# IE8 - jQuery Slider Next/Prev Buttons Without Link

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am currently stumped on a strange issue. I have a jQuery slider that works fine on all major browsers, yet when I'm on Internet Explorer 8, the Next/Prev buttons do not work (as in, they do not have a link when hovered on).

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="frame"></div>
    <div id="slides">
        <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
        <a href="#" class="next"></a>
        <div class="slides_container">
            <img src="images/slider/4.jpg" width="954" height="247" alt="Slide 1">
            <img src="images/slider/4.jpg" width="954" height="247" alt="Slide 2">
            <img src="images/slider/4.jpg" width="954" height="247" alt="Slide 3">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 964px;
    height: 257px;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    position: relative;
}

#frame {
    background: url('../images/slider/slider_frame.png') no-repeat;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000, 0 0 6px #000000;
    height: 257px;
    left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    width: 964px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

/*
    Slideshow
*/

#slides {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    z-index: 100;
    left: 5px;
    width: 954px;
    height: 247px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/*
    Slides container
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides container
    Set to display none, prevents content flash
*/

.slides_container {
    width: 954px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

/*
    Each slide
    Important:
    Set the width of your slides
    If height not specified height will be set by the slide content
    Set to display block
*/

.slides_container a {
    width: 570px;
    height: 270px;
    display: block;
}

.slides_container a img {
    display: block;
}

/*
    Next/prev buttons
*/

#slides .next, #slides .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 101;
}

#slides .next {
    background-image: url('../images/slider/arrow-right.png');
}

#slides .next:hover {
    background-image: url('../images/slider/arrow-right-hov.png');
}

#slides .prev {
    background-image: url('../images/slider/arrow-left.png');
}

#slides .prev:hover {
    background-image: url('../images/slider/arrow-left-hov.png');
}

#slides .next {
    left: 906px;
}
```

To essentially rephrase my issue:
I have an image within this jQuery slider that has the purpose to switch slides. However, this said image does not have a link in IE8, thus not allowing a user using IE8 to scroll between slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css classes have z-index problems as i see the css:

```
#frame {
background: url('../images/slider/slider_frame.png') no-repeat;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000, 0 0 6px #000000;
height: 257px;
left: 0;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
top: -5px;
width: 964px;
z-index: 99999; // <-----------------this has the higher index.
}

#slides .next, #slides .prev {
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
width: 48px;
height: 48px;
display: block;
z-index: 101; //<--------------------this has a lower index
}
```

try to either `interchange the z-indexes` or `make a new higher z-index` for clicking buttons.

try this and see if this helps you.

Comment: Have to wait 2 more minutes :P